# How to print incoming packets in Contiki OS?

Tags: c, contiki

I need to print the content of each incoming packet (data, routing, ICMP, ...) on Contiki OS 2.7 to the serial for debugging.

I found that the function `packetbuf_dataptr()` of `/core/net/packetbuf.c` points to the header of the inbound packet. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to get the bytes, and I don't know how to use it?

Comment: We are not a tutiring site. DO you have a **specific** problem?

Comment: Sidenote: forwarding each and every packet is hardly a good idea. What if you run out of buffers, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
uint16_t i;
uint16_t len = packetbuf_datalen();
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  printf("%02x ", ((uint8_t *)packetbuf_dataptr())[i]);
}
```

Look at the `examples/sensniff/` for a IEEE 802.15.4 packet sniffer application that simply prints out all received frames. You can integrate the Sensniff with Wireshark, running on the PC side if you're so inclined.